# Undefined reference to asio::ip::basic_endpoint

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I have a Socket class as -

```
Socket(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep);
```

I want the second param to be either a tcp or udp endpoint.
For this, I have made the Socket class a template -

```
 Socket(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, T ep);
```

I then instantiate an object of Socket with -

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), 1235);  
Socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint> obj(io_service, ep);
```

On compilation, I get the error:

```
(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `Socket<boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::Socket(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp>)'
```

I have included the headers 'boost/asio.hpp' & 'boost/asio/ip/basic_endpoint.hpp' and compile using -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread on Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Box.

Could someone please help resolve this issue?

Edit:
Boost version - Boost version: 1.65.1

Build Command:

```
g++ ApplicationMain.cpp Socket.cpp -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread -o output.out
```

I am pasting my code as is:

```
//*******Socket.h

template <typename T>
class Socket {
private:
    tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;

public:
    Socket(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, T ep);
};


//*******Socket.cpp

template <typename T>
Socket<T>::Socket(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, T ep): mAcceptor(ioService, ep)
{ 
}

//*******ApplicationMain.cpp

int main()
{
    printf("Main Start!\n");
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), 1235);
    Socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint> obj(io_service, ep);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the *exact* command you use to build. [Edit] your question and copy-paste (as text!) the command into it.

Comment: Also include the boost version you use. There has been some breaking changes in boost::asion over the years.

Comment: Possibly related (concerning your own template definitions): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: Now when the error messages have been better formatted, it's easier to see that the problem is your own `Socket` class template. And it indeed looks like a duplicate of the question @πάνταῥεῖ linked to.

Comment: I believe, I have created the template class correctly. But there could be some mistake, its something I am unable to figure out :(

Comment: Read the duplicate answers, either move your template class into the header file or use the workarounds to instantiate it in the cpp file

Comment: Adding the implementation to the header file, resolved my error. Thank you!!!